# Rename files in subfolders using if()

Tags: powershell, pdf

I am trying to rename PDF files using comma separated values. When all my PDFs were in one folder, the following script worked:

```
$myHeader = echo fileName newName

Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\list_names.txt -Header $myHeader | foreach {
    if (Test-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot\*.pdf) {
        Rename-Item $_.fileName $_.newName
    }
}
```

However, after reorganizing the PDFs into subfolders, the script no longer works since the paths of the PDF files are now `$PSScriptRoot\subfolder1\*.pdf` or `$PSScriptRoot\subfolder2\*.pdf`, etc.

`Test-Path` doesn't work with subfolders, and I have also tried to change the script using `Get-ChildItem` and other commands to no avail. I'm not sure how to fix this script to work with subfolders.

**Edit:** I only have the file names in the CSV. It has just two columns:

```
"oldfilename.pdf","newfilename.pdf"
```

Comment: So in your csv, do you have only the file names or do you have the file name and the subfolder?

Comment: Yeah, it would be useful to have an example of one record of the CSV. Also, did you try Get-ChildItem with the -Recurse switch ? You need to add that switch to get subfolders content enumerated too.

Comment: @MaximeFranchot I have edited my question to show an example of the records in the CSV.

Comment: @SagePourpre Yes, I tried using get-childitem with -recurse and I have also tried creating a variable $files= get-childitem $PSScriptRoot -recurse. Perhaps I've placed it incorrectly within the foreach {} argument, but I'm not sure where to place it in my script.

Comment: Just in case that didn't become clear the last time: `$myHeader = echo fileName newName` is a very awkward way of expressing `$myHeader = 'fileName', 'newName'`.

Answer (score 4):

If you know that all files of interest are located directly in immediate subfolders of the script's folder, you can use `Resolve-Path` to find each file of interest:

```
$myHeader= 'fileName', 'newName'

Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\list_names.txt -Header $myHeader | ForEach-Object { 
  if ($file = Resolve-Path "$PSScriptRoot\*\$($_.filename)") { 
    Rename-Item $file $_.newName -WhatIf
  } 
}
```

If no matching file is found in any immediate subfolder, the `Resolve-Path` call outputs nothing, and the `if` block isn't entered. If there is a match, it is assigned to variable `$file`, and the `if` block is entered.

The `-WhatIf` previous the renaming operations; remove it to perform actual renaming.

---

If, by contrast, the files of interest can be located anywhere in the script's folder subtree, use [Maxime Franchot's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46046334/45375).

Comment: Are you sure this only works for the immediate subfolders? I would think that the wildcard " * " can stand for "subfolder\subsubfolder", making it go to all levels in the path. But thanks for the link anyways ;)

Comment: @MaximeFranchot: Yes, it only works with immediate subfolders: `*` covers only _one_ level of the folder hierarchy. `bash` (v4+), for instance, has option `globstar` so that `**` matches in the entire subtree, but, as far as I know, PowerShell has no equivalent in its wildcard pattern syntax.

Comment: I hope it was clear that I was just stating what I thought, so thank you for the correction :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with. It puts the CSV content into a hashtable with Key = OldName, Value = NewName. Then, it runs through all the subfolders in the root path. If you want, you can use the `-exclude` or `-include` parameters, or remove the `-recurse` parameter, etc. to make the search faster and more precise.

```
$CSVHashTable = @{}
Import-CSV $PSScriptRoot\list_names.txt | 
%{$CsvHashTable.Add($_.FileName, $_.NewName)}

Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -File -Recurse | 
?{$CsvHashTable.ContainsKey($_.Name)} |
Rename-Item {$CsvHashTable.Item($_.Name)}
```

Comment: Also, the Hashtable prevents multiple files of the same name (though different subfolders) from being added. You can probably get this information after the `.Add` method on the third line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not familiar with hashtables. When I tried to run this I got an error message saying: "Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.""

Comment: That's strange, it seems to be a problem with your CSV. What happens if you do `Import-CSV $PSScriptRoot\list_names.txt`? Does it output the contents of the CSV correctly? How about if you do `Import-CSV $PSScriptRoot\list_names.txt | Select -ExpandProperty FileName`? This will check if "FileName" is the correct header, which I can't tell you if it is or not :P

Comment: Apparently the input CSV doesn't have headers, so importing without `-Header` won't work correctly.

Comment: In that case, you have to list the headers with that parameter. If your file has columns: FileNames, then NewName, then the header parameter must be `-Header "FileName", "NewName"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a csv built like this

```
ss1.pdf,tt1.pdf                                       
Sub1\ss2.pdf,tt2.pdf                                  
Sub1\Sub2\ss3.pdf,tt3.pdf
```

The following script does the job properly.

```
function Rename-Pdfs($Path,$items) {

foreach ($item in $items) {
    $OldName = $Path + $item.fileName    


     if (Test-Path $OldName) {
        Rename-Item $OldName $item.newName
     }
 }
}


$myHeader = echo fileName newName
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\__tmp\MyCSV.csv' -Header 'fileName','newName'


Rename-Pdfs -Path 'C:\__tmp\'  -items $csv
```

Without using a function and with PSScriptRoot

```
$items = Import-Csv 'C:\__tmp\MyCSV.csv' -Header 'fileName','newName'

foreach ($item in $items) {

    $OldName = $PSScriptRoot + '\' +  $item.fileName    

     if (Test-Path $OldName) {
        Rename-Item $OldName $item.newName
     }
 }
```

Take notice that in that last example, I modified $oldPath to include the otherwise missing backslash which is not added to PsScriptRoot and not inside my csv first column (fileName).

If you have still issue, try to include some Write-Host command so you can gain more insight into the matter by viewing values.

Comment: You're solving a different problem. The OP has stated that the CSV file contains filenames only, no paths.

Comment: OP mentionned some files were in subfolders. I assumed they were referenced in the filename relative to the root folder. Otherwise, I guess the solution would be to recurse until the name is found but it could create issues with 2 files named the same way in different folder level if you were to rename based solely on the name without some reference to the location.